# Pyplot (random?) variations in plot size with static rcParams

Tags: javascript, python, matplotlib

I am using Jupyter notebook to run a large-ish program in steps. As part of the code - in order to get the graphs that I am plotting to be visible in non-scrolling windows  - I am using:

```
%%javascript
IPython.OutputArea.prototype._should_scroll = function(lines) {
    return false;
}
```

Which I originally found on stackoverflow.

I am also using:

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [16,12]
```

(matplotlib.pyplot as plt, as usual) in order to control the size of the output plots.

The data is read in and the code loops through it. In the section doing the plotting (all inside one loop) it is producing a number of plots at the right size, with the correct annotations, and then it will suddenly and apparently produce a valid diagram but reduced to postage stamp size. It will do this for a few plots - and then revert to normal size and then do the same thing again.

The above is the only code I am using to explicitly control plot sizes and both sit outside the loop. Inside the loop - and each time it is executed - there are multiple calls to plt routines.

It's almost as if the parameters in plt.rcParams are being over-written but since they are outside the loop, they shouldn't be shouldn't they?

Any thoughts on why this is happening? -and of course how to fix it. Can overplotting (which I am doing on some plots) have something to do with it? Should the javascript be modified?

Many thanks

Comment: This is unexpected. Try to create a [mcve]. Then share this example code here.

Comment: I will try, but the code is large and involves calls to various libraries, some standard, some custom and third party astronomical datasets. I guess that what I was wondering if there was a known issue with either the Javascript or rcParams. BTW, I turned off overplotting and that made no difference

Comment: Creating a [mcve] may sometimes be hard, but it's the only way to tackle such problems. Note that such issues are never depending on the actual dataset, and most probably your custom libraries are also not doing any harm - or if they are, then you would find out by creating the minimal example.

Comment: I will have a try. It may not be today, or tomorrow due to pressure of (other) work, but...

Comment: OK. I have created a set of code, minimal it ain't but it does throw away a lot of code.

Comment: OK. I have created a set of code, minimal it ain't but it does throw away a lot of code. What happens is this: if I take a copy of the custom library function and embed it in the main notebook and call (say) plot_thing (some list of args) it can be got to do the plotting as it should with rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [16,12] . If I call this as part of a library eg. L2U.plot_thing (some list of args), then in that case the plot reduces to some default size which is tiny. The library L2U is linked in when I restart the kernel in the Jupyter notebook via an import( import Library_name as L2U).

Comment: As far as I can see the options are: (i) for some reason rcParams isn't passed through correctly; (ii) there is an issue with linking the library (which may be a superset of (i)); (iii)  there is an issue with (my implementation of?) Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the more I look at it and try to create a MRE (see comments above), the more I come to the conclusion that the issue is something in the way that I am passing "stuff" between the calling routines and the library. As such it is an idiosyncracy of my code/system and probably not of wider interest. If something of general interst comes up I will post it here or in an appropriate spot.

========================================================================

That was my initial response last month, however having looked into this much further it appears **not** to be an issue with passing between the libraries and the calling program, as it also occurs in programs that don't call the libraries. It appears to be something in the way that rcParams interacts with Jupyter notebook as configured on my machine (which is a fairly basic configuration).

I am unable to take thisd further at the present time.

Comment: Having looked into this further it appears **not** to be an issue with passing between the libraries and the calling program.